# Apagar registros de checkboxes selecionadas com angular

Tags: angular, checkbox

Preciso criar uma função que apague os registros de acordo com o(s) checkbox(es) selecionado(s).
Consegui fazer a seleção destes IDs referente a cada checkbox e inclusão dos mesmos na array "**selected**" atraves da função **alternaSelecao()**, porem agora preciso criar uma função para excluir estes **ids** armazenados em "**selected**" que correspondem a registros do array principal "**pessoasArray**".

html

```
<tr *ngFor="let pessoa of pessoasArray; let i = index">
                <th><input type="checkbox" name="" (click)="alternaSelecao(pessoa)"/></th>
                <!-- <th>{{pessoa.$key}}</th> -->
                <td>{{ i+1 }}</td>
                <td>{{pessoa.nome}}</td>
                <td>{{pessoa.email}}</td>
                <td>{{pessoa.tipo}}</td>
                <td>{{pessoa.datanasc}}</td>
                <td>
```

classe

```
export class PessoaComponent implements OnInit {

  constructor(public bd: Bd) { }

  selected = [];
  public pessoasArray

  ngOnInit() {
    this.bd.getPessoas().subscribe(
      list => {
        this.pessoasArray = list.map(item => {
          return {
            $key: item.key,
            ...item.payload.val()
          };

        });
      });    

  }

alternaSelecao(pessoa) {
    let idx = this.selected.indexOf(pessoa);
    if(idx > -1){
      this.selected.splice(idx,1);
    }
    else {
      this.selected.push(pessoa);
    }     
  }
```

service *bd*:

```
export class Bd {

constructor(private firebase: AngularFireDatabase) { }
    public pessoasList: AngularFireList<any>;

    public getPessoas() {
    this.pessoasList = this.firebase.list('pessoa');
    return this.pessoasList.snapshotChanges();

    }
```

Comment: Você poderia me passar um array contendo a lista?

Answer (score 0):

Não sei se entendi completamente sua pergunta, mas se vc tiver apenas tentando limpar a array *Selected*
Então basta você:

**Metodo :**

```
clearArray(){
     this.selected.splice(0,myArray.lenght);
}
```

ou pode escolher outas variações como:

```
while(myArray.lenght >  0 ){
   myArray.pop();
}
```

Ou

```
myArray.lenght = 0;
```

Comment: na verdade estou conseguindo limpar o array _Selected_. O que eu preciso é usar estes ids contidos em _selected_ para comparar e apagar com seus correspondentes no banco. Em _ngOnInit_ eu faço um subscribe do firebase recebido em _pessoasArray_ que eu uso para mostrar no HTML. Acabei de acrescentar o service para melhor entendimento.